# Invalid node count in MPI pi calculation

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, openmpi

I am trying to parallelize the following code for calculation of pi.

My approach is to use scatter to parallelize the for, and then use a reduce to calculate the sum value and finally show pi.

My code is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h> 

long num_steps = 100000;
double step = 1.0/100000.0;

int main() {

int i, myid, size;
double x, pi, local_sum = 0.0, sum=0.0;
double send_vec[num_steps], recv_vect[num_steps]; 

// Initialize the MPI environment 
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL); 
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); 
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);

if (myid ==0){
    int i=0; 
    for (i=0; i<num_steps;i++){
        send_vec[i]=i;
    }
}

MPI_Scatter(send_vec, num_steps/size, MPI_INT, recv_vect, 
    num_steps, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

for(i = 0; i < num_steps; ++i) {
    x = (recv_vect[i]-0.5)*step;
    local_sum += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
}

MPI_Reduce(&local_sum, &sum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (myid == 0){
    pi = step*sum;
    printf("PI value = %f\n", pi);  
 }

// Finalize the MPI environment. 
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The thing is when I run the program with the option -np 1 and 2
I do get the desired result.

Yet when I run with 3, 4 and higher I get the following error:

```
PIC_Send(284).........: Negative count, value is -240000
Fatal error in PMPI_Scatter: Invalid count, error stack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `MPI_Scatter()` is to be corrected:

```
MPI_Scatter(send_vec, num_steps/size, MPI_INT, recv_vect, 
num_steps, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

- To send `double`, use the datatype `MPI_DOUBLE` as you did in the `MPI_Reduce()`
- Since the `sendtype` is similar to the `recvtype`, the number of item sent to each process `sendcount` must be equal to the number of item received by each process `recvcount`. In the present case, it's `num_steps/size`.

Finally, the call to `MPI_Scatter()` will look like:

```
MPI_Scatter(send_vec, num_steps/size, MPI_DOUBLE, recv_vect, 
num_steps/size, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Lastly, dynamic memory allocation can be used to avoid using the stack for storing large arrays. Moreover, the allocated space can be decreased so as to reduce the memory footprint:

```
num_steps=(num_steps/size)*size;
double* send_vec=NULL;
double* recv_vec=NULL;
if(rank==0){
   send_vec=malloc((num_steps/size)*sizeof(double));
   if(send_vec==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
}
recv_vec=malloc(num_steps*sizeof(double));
if(recv_vec==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}

...

if(rank==0){
   free(send_vec);
}
free(recv_vec);
```

Comment: I works. Thank you. Could you explain why the receive size has to be: num_steps/size? Is it because I am receiving everything I sent?

Comment: As specified in the [documentation of openmpi about `MPI_Scatter()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.5/man3/MPI_Scatter.3.php), the argument `sendcount` must be the "Number of elements sent to each process"  and `recvcount` must be "Number of elements in receive buffer". If `num_steps/size` elements of type `double` are sent to each process, each process will receive `num_steps/size` of type `double`.

Comment: See also p160 of the [MPI standards 3.1](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) about `MPI_Scatter()`: `The type signature associated with
sendcount,  sendtype
at the root must be equal to
the type signature associated with
recvcount,  recvtype
at all processes (however, the type
maps may be different).  This implies that the amount of data sent must be equal to the
amount of data received, pairwise between each process and the root.  Distinct type maps
between sender and receiver are still allowed.`